# How to use EXISTS method in Table of Table type (matrix table) to find if a value is present

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The below script is for creating and adding values to a table of table type. 
How to use EXISTS method in this table to find out if a value is present in a cell?

```
DECLARE
   TYPE RecType IS RECORD
   (
      value1   NUMBER,
      value2   NUMBER,
      value3   NUMBER
   );
   TYPE TblType IS TABLE OF RecType INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;  
   TYPE TblOfTblType IS TABLE OF TblType INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   matrix   TblOfTblType;

BEGIN
   /*Writing the data*/
   FOR i IN 4 .. 6 LOOP
      FOR j IN 1 .. 3 LOOP
         matrix (i) (j).value1 := i * j;
         matrix (i) (j).value2 := i + j;
         matrix (i) (j).value3 := i - j;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Just curious, [do you have two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45564132/266304), or is that someone else doing the same course?

Comment: haha...nope..this is my only account in SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first check if the row exists, and only then check if the column exists in that row (or x then y, or i then j, or however you want to identify a cell).

For example, to check if cell (1,2) exists in your example:

```
  if matrix.exists(1) and matrix(1).exists(2) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('No');
  end if;
```

which outputs 'No'.

And to check if cell (6,3) exists:

```
  if matrix.exists(6) and matrix(6).exists(3) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('No');
  end if;
```

which outputs 'Yes'.

Notice that it is two steps; if `matrix.exists(1)` is false then you don't attempt to look for `matrix(1).exists(2)`. If you didn't have the first check and only did:

```
  if matrix(1).exists(2) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('No');
  end if;
```

you'd get an `ORA-01403: no data found` exception.